# Could not resolve type name: SitecoreContrib.Serialization.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.RewriteUrl

Tags: sitecore

It look like a missing reference or a reference with a different version. I just can't tell with dll is responsible for that call or maybe it's a Sitecore config issue.[image]

Comment: Seems like custom code, it not something out of the box. The DLL name you name scrubbed out is the one that is responsible. Check your configs (or use `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`) to figure out where that processor is patched in and remove it or fix the referebce.

Comment: @jammykam I can't even access backend to look at the configs

Comment: Is this on your local machine? Or deployed server? Can you not look in the file system for references?

Comment: Local machine(server) I have access to the file system

Comment: So check the file system... use a tool like [GrepWin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html) so search the content of all the config files for references to `RewriteUrl`...

Answer (score 0):

You will find your answer here. Its is community code.

http://www.sitecore.net/en-gb/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/dirk-schafauer/posts/2014/05/configure-the-maxjsonlength-property-for-your-needs.aspx

Here is another link, same code.
http://seitenkern.com/tag/json-serialization/